# "PUT" request with oauth2

Tags: java, http, servlets, https, oauth-2.0

Can I use a "PUT" request with oauth2?
I have written a REST API, application using Java servelet.
When I use "POST" request, I am given a succeeded response with access_token.

But, when I use "PUT" request, I am given following error.

> {"error_description":"Missing grant_type parameter value","error":"invalid_request"}

I have clealy configured the things PUT request as well as POST request as follows.

**POST request**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    try
    {
      handleGrants(request, response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      response.getWriter().write("Error in Authentication System!! ");
      logger.error("Failed trying to get tokens", e);
    }
    finally
    {
      response.getWriter().flush();
      response.getWriter().close();
    }
}
```

**PUT request**

```
public void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    try
    {
      handleGrants(request, response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      response.getWriter().write("Error in Authentication System!! ");
      logger.error("Failed trying to get tokens", e);
    }
    finally
    {
      response.getWriter().flush();
      response.getWriter().close();
    }
}
```

my body parameters for both "PUT" and "POST" request as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given error, what I can say is that your **handleGrants** method is not getting request body. Thus it says grant type cannot be determined. May be you should debug and see the parameter usage inside the function.

Regardless, OAuth 2.0 mandate to use **POST** for token endpoint.

**[3.2.  Token Endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2)**

> The client **MUST** use the HTTP "POST" method when making access token
> requests.

So please stick to what specification says and use POST.

**Appendix**

According to [RFC2119](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119)

> **MUST**
>
> This word, or the terms "REQUIRED" or "SHALL", mean that the definition is an absolute requirement of the specification.

Comment: That means, can't we use PUT request for this scenario?

Comment: @PubuduMaheshMeththananda when dealing with RFC documents, you must adhere to wording in them. They are called Notational Conventions. RFC6749 define them (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.9) and refer to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119. So yes you must use POST for token request. Probably this issue is due to that

Comment: Also, I am not sure why you require PUT for token request. If this identity provider (authorization server) is a custom implementation, you may try on giving support to that. But as mentioned above it is a violation of the protocol requirement. So keep that in mind